# How to upload image from UIImagePickerController to any server in IOS

Tags: ios, upload, uiimagepickercontroller, afnetworking

I using following codes to implement upload image to server choosing from UIImagePickerController (using AFNETWorking library) :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    UIImage *imageIWantToUpload = imageupload;
    NSData *dataToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageIWantToUpload, 0.5);


    // Create the NSData object for the upload process

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"iosuploads.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        NSLog(@"strimng");
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToUpload name:@"uploadedfile" fileName:@"attachment.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        NSLog(@"strimng");
    }];
    NSLog(@"strimng");


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
   [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

When I build and run it on iphone, in console show size of image uploading but in server is not found image which has just uploaded.

I create account in 000webhost to test but I use account FTP in it to test. I don't know I must use what URL to upload file?

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FTP instead of HTTP.

You can upload / download an image to the server using FTP , not using HTTP.

Try this [FTPHelper](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper)

Comment: @HTKT - Ya you can use that link to upload file to any server

Answer (score 0):

Download files from [here.](https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest)
Here is the code to upload image on ftp server.

```
NSString *ftpUrl=@"ftp://yourftp Url";
NSString *strPortNumber=@"port Number";
NSString *strurlUpload=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",ftpUrl,strPortNumber];

NSString *getfilePath=@"Your Image file path";
SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurlUpload] toUploadFile:getfilePath];
ftpRequest.username = @"Username";
ftpRequest.password = @"password";
ftpRequest.delegate = self;
ftpRequest.didFinishSelector = @selector(uploadFinished:);
ftpRequest.didFailSelector = @selector(uploadFailed:);
ftpRequest.willStartSelector = @selector(uploadWillStart:);
ftpRequest.didChangeStatusSelector = @selector(requestStatusChanged:);
ftpRequest.bytesWrittenSelector = @selector(uploadBytesWritten:);
[ftpRequest startRequest];
```

Getting file path from the UIImagepickerController.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    // Here is the file path for the image
    NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagename.png"]];
    [imageData writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How to get filepath in UIImagePickercontroller ?